# Which add-ins I need to add in UFT One so that frame class should be SAPFrame?

Tags: hp-uft, uft14, microfocus

I am using uft one with the add-ins as shown in image. But frame class is identifying as FRAME, I need frame class as SAPFrame. Please let me know which add-in should I add. Thanks.[image: Add-ins which I have added in my UFT One]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've dealt with SAP on UFT, I think you should only have the top level SAP addin (without it's children) and Web selected.

It's better to deselect unused addins as they may interfere with the ones you actually need.

Comment: Thanks Motti. As per further research I found that version of UFT one and  UFT Agent in chrome was not matching. I am using latest UFT One(15.0) and I had old version of UFT Agent in chrome.